# Django.contrib.auth and post_migrate

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-1.10

I am currently extending `django.contrib.auth`. One of the features I need is generating [Groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#group-model) and associated [Permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#permission-model) based on some rules defined in project settings.

The perfect place to do so would be the [post_migrate signal](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3c447b108ac70757001171f7a4791f493880bf5b/django/db/models/signals.py). However, `django.contrib.auth` has a `post_migrate` receiver (connected [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f3ea0c4bbd5fa9bac73049839ce5de388d53371a/django/contrib/auth/apps.py)) that runs `create_permissions` ([here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f3ea0c4bbd5fa9bac73049839ce5de388d53371a/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py)).

Since I rely on permissions generated by `django.contrib.auth`, I need to ensure that my `create_groups` always runs *after* the permissions were created by `django.contrib.auth` `create_permissions`.

What would be the best approach to do so?

Comment: I've asked something similar, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446788/defining-a-custom-post-migrate-signal

Comment: @slackmart I cannot see how it is related to my problem, I don't have any problem with not being able to register for ```post_migrate```.

Comment: Ok. just ignore it.